# Minkowski signature convention and propagator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, conventions, propagator

Planar waves with positive energy are usually defined

$$
e^{-ipx}
$$

where (I suppose) the west coast metric $(+,-,-,-)$ has been used.

Since the east coast metric $(-,+,+,+)$ switches the sign of the scalar product $px$, the positive energy planar waves read

$$
e^{ipx}
$$

Is that correct so far?

If yes, then shouldn't the quantum propagator $e^{-iHt}$ be written as $e^{iHt}$ in the east coast metric?

I'm asking because of a confusion: I'm pretty sure I have seen both $e^{-ipx}$ and $e^{ipx}$ as positive energy plane waves, but I have never stumbled across a $e^{iHt}$ propagator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The convention on the Minkowski metric is only used to write scalar products. In your case, in the West Coast metric, a plane wave with positive energy is given, as you said, by $e^{-i p^\mu x_\mu}$: this is written in components as $e^{-i Et}e^{i \vec p\cdot \vec x}$, and that's a positive energy wave because of the Schrodinger's equation
$$
i\partial_tf(\vec x,t)=E f(\vec x,t)
$$
If you use your plane wave as $f$, you'll see that the equation is solved. That's why it is a positive energy solution. $e^{i p^\mu x_\mu}$, for similar reasons, is the plane wave with negative energy: you can see that it solves
$$
i\partial_t f(\vec x,t)=-Ef(\vec x,t)
$$
so it has energy $-E$.

You are correct in saying that, in the case of the other metric, the roles are apparently switched: $e^{i p_\mu x^\mu}$ is the positive energy wave, while $e^{-i p_\mu x^\mu}$ is the negative energy wave. The fact is that, when you do the scalar product you will obtain the same expressions as before: $e^{i p_\mu x^\mu}$ written in East Coast convention evaluates to $e^{-i E t}e^{i\vec p\cdot\vec x}$, so it's the same as writing $e^{-i p_\mu x^\mu}$. As you can see, once we write the scalar products in terms of the components of the vectors you get the same thing as before.

So, the reason for $U(t)=\exp(-i H t)$ is not related to any metric convention, but it comes from Schrodinger's equation.